# Limited incremental scrolling (hopefully with jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I want to limit the amount a person can scroll at one time so they transition through slides on a website sequentially.

Here's an example: http://www.apple.com/mac-pro/

No matter how much you scroll, you'll be transitioned to the next/prev slide one at a time (unless you select a slide in which case you're transitioned straight to it). Hoping I can do it relatively easily with jQuery by intercepting when the user scrolls.

*P.S. Sorry about the ambiguous title - bit difficult to know what I'm asking.*

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea of how to go about it. Why not give it a try, then come back when you hit a snag?

Comment: I have no idea at all. Was hoping someone implemented something similar and could share some insight

Comment: Ah okay, no worries. I recommend taking a look at the mac pro page with your web inspector. As you can see, they actually load the DOM with all of the sections available. What they do is show/hide with super fancy transitions. In terms of scrolling, you'd basically want to watch for the user either scrolling to the top of the page, or the bottom of the page, then load the content dynamically. Scroll up to load the previous section, scroll down to show the next one. Kind of like you would do a scrolling "load-more" on a twitter feed or something... Hopefully that makes some sense. :)

Comment: Looks like there isn't really any scrolling going on with that website--overflow is set to hidden on the container elements that would typically be where scrolling occurs. Looks like they're just listening for mouse-wheel events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example of how you could script the actual mechanics behind knowing the user's scroll state. Open up your browser console and watch the logs as you mouse up and down. I've also added in an event pause for animation between slides.

The one drawback to my approach here is that it relies on there being an actual scrollable element. I've included a basic event handler for a really cool plugin called [jQuery Mouse Wheel Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) which doesn't rely on scrolling of an element. It actually listens to mousewheel events. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work... so I just stuck with my method for purposes of the demo.

Hopefully this helps, and let me know if you have any questions!

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/YF4HY/

```
$(function () {
    var scroll      = 0, //how many times have we scrolled
        scroll_max  = 15, //how many times we want to scroll per slide
        prev_scroll = 0, //what was the last scrollTop? We need this to know up from down
        slide       = 0, //this can be whatever you want, but this just tracks the current slide
        slide_max   = 5, //how many slides we have
        animated    = false; //are we animating? if so, we want to cancel the scroll handler

    function scrollUp () {
        if(scroll === 0 && slide < 1){
          console.log('beginning of slides');
        } else if (scroll > 0) {
            scroll--;
        } else if (scroll === 0 && slide > 0) {
            simulateAnimation(slideBackward);//CHANGE SLIDES AND CANCEL THE SCROLL EVENT

        }
    }

    function scrollDown () {
        if(scroll === scroll_max && slide === slide_max){
          console.log('top of slides');
        } else if (scroll < scroll_max) { //normal scroll up
            scroll++;
        } else if (scroll === scroll_max && slide < slide_max) {
            simulateAnimation(slideForward);//CHANGE SLIDES AND CANCEL THE SCROLL EVENT  
        }
    }

    function slideForward () {
        scroll = 0;
        slide++;
        animated = false;
    }


    function slideBackward () {
        scroll = scroll_max;
        slide--;
        animated = false;
    }

    //figured out which direction we scrolled
    function determineScrollDirection (current_scroll) {
        var prev = prev_scroll;
        prev_scroll = current_scroll;
        return (current_scroll > prev) ? 'down' : 'up';
    }

    function simulateAnimation (handler) {
        animated = true;
        setTimeout(handler, 2000);
    }

    $(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
        if(!animated){
            switch (determineScrollDirection($(this).scrollTop())) {
                case 'down':
                    scrollDown();
                    break;
                case 'up':
                    scrollUp();
                    break;
            }
            console.log({slide:slide, scroll:scroll});
        } else {
          console.log('Don\'t do anything because we are changing slides.');
        }
    });

    // YOU MIGHT BE ABLE TO USE THIS TO LISTEN TO MOUSEWHEEL EVENTS ACCURATELY WITH NO SCROLL
    // https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/
    $(document).on('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        //console.log(delta, deltaX, deltaY);
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks like a great start. Thanks for your help